# ModuleNotFoundError: No Module named PIL while runnung Pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I am converting a python script to an exe using Pyinstaller. But the error "ModuleNotFoundError: No Module named PIL" is shown:

[image]

What can I do to resolve this error and any similiar ones that pop-up in the future?

Comment: Maybe try to redo the installation?

Comment: Or use auto-py-to-exe

Comment: pip install auto-py-to-exe and then continue like that

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't work. The same error is shown.